# In Linux Mint, how do I see my recently installed applications?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, cinnamon

I'd like to see a list of the programs I recently installed. Can this be done or is there an extension to support such a feature? I am using Cinnamon 19 Tara. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/var/log/dpkg.log` with your favourite text viewer.

Comment: Oh, I found it. It's not very organized though, and it also includes every extension, package and library installed along the way...